# How can I use an MDX Level property in the slicer?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

Suppose I have a [Sales] cube which has a [Store] level and a store has a "type" property.
Which query should I use for showing the sum of sales for all the stores of type "Supermarket"?
(e.g. You sold 6M $ in all stores of type "Supermarket")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access member properties, you can use `.properties("propertyname")`

You would have to create a custom set which first filtered and then aggregated all the members of the [Store] level which matched the property value "Supermarket".

My MDX skills are a bit rusty...

```
WITH MEMBER [Stores].[SupermarketSweep] AS 'Aggregate([Filter([Stores].[Store].members, [Stores].currentMember.properties("type") = "Supermarket"))'
SELECT {[Stores].[SupermarketSweep]} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[Whatever]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the "type" property in queries you would be better to make it a browseable attribute.